# Ajax Login issues with Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Login via Ajax is not working and it is showing login as failed.
Here is a snippet of the code of index file.

```
 $('.signin-button-department').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var short = $.trim($('input[name="short_name"]').val());
    var passs = $.trim($('input[name="inst_password"]').val());

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: {
                short_name: short, 
                 inst_password: passs 
            }

        })
        .done(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (res == 1) {
                window.location.href ="production/institute.php";
            } else {
                alert('Login failed!');
                $('input[name="short_name"]').focus();
                $('input').val('');
            }
        });
}); //Department
```

And this is The `login.php` code.

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    
    $inst_id = $_POST['short_name'];
    $inst_password = md5($_POST['inst_password']);
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE short_name = ?  AND inst_password = ? ";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    $query->execute(array($inst_id,$inst_password));
    $row = $query->fetch();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    
    if ($count > 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['institute_id'];
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
?>
```

Can you please have a look and let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Don't use [md5()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) for password hashing. It even says so in the manual: _"It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm."_ Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) to hash the password and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a  hash against a password on login. This will require you to rewrite your code so I would recommend doing this instead/before you keep debugging.

Comment: The returned response to the ajax callback will be a string - not an integer as you are testing for here. Cast to an int or treat as a string.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - It's JavaScript and they are using a loose type comparison so it should work either way.

Comment: @farhadKhan have you checked ajax response in network tab? Can you share that with us?

Comment: Your code should work, this is probably a problem with the data. Use var_dump() to check the values you receive in PHP after applying MD5 to the password and run the query with theses values directly on the database to see if it returns the expected results

Comment: Or it could be notorious php extra whitespace in response. `trim()` the response string before comparing it's value

Comment: @farhadKhan You may also want to remove the closing ?> tag in your code. These will bring you nothing but trouble if they're at the end of the file....